# LinearLayout Weight issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Well I have a vertical LinearLayout inside a ScrollView, it's a kind of form where I register a payment, the points is than i'm trying to make it responsive, on every thing inside this list view will have a vertical weigh of 1, to make the elements get engages equitably on the reserved space for this LinearLayout, the point is than the linearLayout don't recognyze the "match_parent" element, which it is the list view

```
<ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider_one"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:dividerPadding="5dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/concept_group">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Gasto De:"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Materia Prima"
                        android:id="@+id/materialButton"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Otro Concepto"
                        android:id="@+id/otrosButton"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Monto: "
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/montoEditText"
                    android:layout_weight="3" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/rowConcepto">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:id="@+id/conceptTextView"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Registrar"
                    android:id="@+id/registrarButton"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
           </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I hope you get my point, please I'll be gratefull on any help

Comment: which list view, and no i am not getting your point. Can you be specific, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this on your parent LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">
```

Add weight sum to 3

Don't know will it work or not :/
You should give it a hit.

**EDIT:**
Try adding this in your ScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: @MaToXz you mean that it is not filling up the whole screen?

Comment: The thing is, i have a linearlayout with 2 more linear layout inside on it, every one of those which are inside have layout_weight on 1, i mean i divide the screen in two equitably linear layout, inside the first half linear layout, i have that code, thar listView I'm showing

Comment: @MaToXz Try adding the fillViewport to the ScrollView, you can see that in my edited answer